# Where should I put applications that need data on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-location

I just downloaded Eclipse, and it is packaged as a compressed file. Within is a folder with the application plus configuration and any plugins et cetera. Should I simply put this in my /usr/bin folder? Is the bin path recursive, so that it will execute eclipse/eclipse when I simply write eclipse? All other files in there are simply that - single binaries, and no config-files or such.

Another possibility that occured to me is place the application in a separate folder, create a bash script that simply starts the application in the bin folder. But what folder would be good? I don't really want to contaminate my home folder with machine-wide applications...

You might call me pedantic, but that is because I am. I just want to know what the "convention" is so to speak.

Comment: When installing things manually, one usually does that to **`/usr/local/bin`**.

Comment: @oKtosiTe Well, alright, good catch. But the same issues still apply... If I just chuck the whole folder in there, won't I get conflicts with the files in the eclipse folder which either are bin-files but not once I want registered globally or that are not but might cause conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going for the packaged version that is installed from the repositories is a good default strategy. If you need a bleeding edge version that's not packaged yet, you have a couple of options:

- build a package yourself
- install eclipse into your home directory, you can do it with regular user privileges and keep your system clean

Answer (score 1):

Not a **real** answer to your question, since you asked for the proper way to manually install - but I'd recommend installing it via the package manager. Just install the package `eclipse` from Synaptic/Aptidude, and you don't have to worry about anything.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Apt is a very handy tool, but atleast a few days ago the eclipse repository was outdated, atleast one version behind. Perhaps its fixed now, but still, I'd like to know the best way to manually install since most applications is a version or few behind the latest stable.

Comment: It's particularly handy because you don't have to worry about dependencies. Anyway: It needs to go to ~/opt. Here are detailed instructions from Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE#Download Eclipse